# Reset columns index after reshaping dataframe of stock prices using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe for stocks with their Open and Close price each day.

```
    ticker          Date         Open        Close  
0      CAMT    2021-01-14    24.150000    24.740000  
1      CAMT    2021-01-15    24.540001    24.400000  
2         F    2021-01-14     9.810000    10.170000  
3         F    2021-01-15    10.040000     9.830000  
4      GKOS    2021-01-14    84.050003    86.709999  
5      GKOS    2021-01-15    86.250000    86.339996
```

I created a new dataframe from this one where each row contain one stock and Open/Close columns for each day.
I used this code:

```
df.pivot(index='ticker', values=['Open', 'Close'], columns='Date').reset_index(drop=False)
```

It return this dataframe:

```
     ticker                Open                                   Close
Date        2021-01-14 00:00:00 2021-01-15 00:00:00 2021-01-14 00:00:00 2021-01-15 00:00:00
0      CAMT           24.150000           24.540001           24.740000           24.400000
1         F            9.810000           10.040000           10.170000            9.830000
2      GKOS           84.050003           86.250000           86.709999           86.339996
3      IGBH           25.180000           24.959999           25.110001           24.950001
```

I want to reset indexes on the columns like below:

```
     ticker        Open_14-01-2021      Close_14-01-2021     Open_15-01-2021    Close_15-01-2021     
0      CAMT           24.150000           24.540001           24.740000           24.400000
1         F            9.810000           10.040000           10.170000            9.830000
2      GKOS           84.050003           86.250000           86.709999           86.339996
3      IGBH           25.180000           24.959999           25.110001           24.950001
```

I tried this but didnt worked:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pivot, then use a simple list comprehension to collapse the MultiIndex on the columns into a simple Index by joining the labels for each level. Then we reset the index to move `'ticker'` back into the columns.

```
df = df.pivot(index='ticker', values=['Open', 'Close'], columns='Date')
df.columns = [f'{x}_{y.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}' for x,y in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
  ticker  Open_14-01-2021  Open_15-01-2021  Close_14-01-2021  Close_15-01-2021
0   CAMT        24.150000        24.540001         24.740000         24.400000
1      F         9.810000        10.040000         10.170000          9.830000
2   GKOS        84.050003        86.250000         86.709999         86.339996
```

Comment: return error: "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Timestamp found"

Comment: @khaledkoubaa That's because your dates are `datetime64[ns]`, I had assumed strings. I modified the solution to deal with them, will work now.

Comment: it return this error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' , so I added this to the list comprehension if not isinstance(y, str) and returned this error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 11 elements, new values have 10 elements